How to mock PDFTK in pestphp
Can you help me how to fix this issue. I'm trying to write a unit test that checks the Pdf generation in my application. It was working on my local env but when I tried to upload it in Bitbucket the pipeline fails.
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

mock(Pdf::class)
     ->shouldReceive('saveAs')
     ->andReturn(true);

App\Exceptions\InvalidPdfException: sh: /usr/local/bin/pdftk: not found
at app/helpers/pdf.php:61

function pdftk(string|array|null $filepath = null)
{
    return new PdfTk($filepath, [
        'command' => config('pdf.pdftk_path'),
    ]);
}


Not sure but you might need to install pdftk in your linux pipeline.
